# Order by with multiple key and case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure of the following form

```
SELECT key1 AS FirstKey, key2 AS SecondKey FROM table
ORDER BY
    CASE @sortOrderParam WHEN 'ASC' THEN
        CASE UPPER(@sortColumn)
        WHEN 'blabla' THEN FirstKey
        WHEN 'blibli' THEN FirstKey, SecondKey --Syntax error
        END
    END ASC,
    CASE @sortOrderParam WHEN 'DESC' THEN
    ...
    END DESC
```

However, I have a syntax error when trying to sort by two columns in some case. How can I do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Unless the statement is more complex than what you displayed, it can be efficiently written without a **case** statement.

Comment: It is a bit more complex. How can it be make simpler ?

Comment: Well, your case statement sorted by the **firstKey** or **firstKey** and **SecondKey**; you can simply order by **firstKey, SecondKey** ; That covers ordering by **firstKey** as well.

Comment: Yes, effectively. Thank you. But as you said, my statement is more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Case can only return one particular value, not a set of columns.  You would need to break it down differently, perhaps like:

```
SELECT key1 AS FirstKey, key2 AS SecondKey FROM table
ORDER BY
FirstKey, 
CASE @sortOrderParam WHEN 'ASC' THEN
    CASE UPPER(@sortColumn)
    WHEN 'blibli' THEN SecondKey --only relevant when blibli
    END
END ASC,
CASE @sortOrderParam WHEN 'DESC' THEN
...
END DESC
```

You could also possibly build a sort column by appending if appropriate with your data.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. In your proposal, does the ASC/DESC applies to FirstKey too ?

Comment: I get to what I want using your appending idea ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: **But my above question in the comment section is still valid.**

Comment: You can use ASC or DESC on any of the columns individually and in any combination as you require.  Default is ascending if unspecified.  For instance, you could sort products by price, descending, but for items that are the same price, sort by name alphabetically, ascending.

Comment: Another alternatice, if the ORDER BY is getting too hairy, is to add additional sorting column(s) to the result set and have a simpler ORDER BY.  That column(s) can be built way you can include whatever CASE logic, subqueries, etc., as required.